# Weird Photoshop behavior

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, osx-el-capitan

I'm using Photoshop CC on El Capitan. I was working as usual and when I tried to change windows with Cmd+tab as usual, maybe I pressed a wrong combination or something, but Photoshop disappeared.

I see it's active in the dock, and if I click on it, it seems the program is there, only that invisible. I mean, the bar shows I'm on PS, and even though the screen I see is for any other program (such as Safari or Firefox) I can't do anything on those programs, because I'm on Photoshop. See image below for explanation:

[image]

(note the black screen you see behind is not Photoshop canvas, it's my desktop)

What can I do to solve this? I tried resetting windows, re-arranging, trying different key combinations I could have touched by accident and nothing worked.
The problem is I was working on a pretty large file and I'm not 100% confident it will recover everything, so trying to minimize losses

**EDIT:** I could save my work by going to `Window--> New Window for [document name]` and then I could save the file (I couldn't save the original, weird), then closed PS, re-opened and everything worked fine again. So the most important part (for me) was solved. However, have no idea what happened there!

Comment: Check Activity Monitor to see if it's gone Not Responding. If it has, you can either try wait it out, or force quit it. If it hasn't, Save your work, if the menus are responding correctly. Ctrl/Tab steps through open files [which you can check in the window menu, though you can't have any menu open whilst doing ctrl/tab, or it moves the selected menu instead], so you can make sure all are saved before quitting.

Comment: @Tetsujin, many thanx. I solved it in another way since nothing worked for the current window (all commands were grayed out) but creating a new window for the document did the trick. How weird...

Comment: Hmm... yup. Chalk it up to gremlins ;)